# Implementing a custom ConcurrentHashMap for database web application

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jakarta-ee, salesforce

Im working on a project for an internship & I'm trying to go about making a subclass of ConcurrentHashMap where the key is going to be the primary key for a database in MS SQL Server 2008, and the value is an FTP link to an associated image, using Apache Commons Net library for the FTP access, and that's all working.

My question is if it's advisable to use ConncurrentHashMap for this, since the code will be running from a managed web application platform called m-Power (for more info http://www.mrc-productivity.com) as a means to prepare data for Bulk Upload into Salesforce.

The reasons I thought to use ConcurrentHashMap was since multiple users would be using the web form at the same time and would therefore be adding/updating records in the SQL Server database at the same time. I also needed a custom implementation since I can add utility functions to the custom class. Any help is welcome :)

Comment: I can say that you are in the right track. ConcurrentHashMap is a right choice as far as I am concerned. I have not worked with m-power but I don't believe it would make too much difference. Good luck =]

Comment: You should make a new class delegates ConcurrentHashMap.  If you make a sabuclass, all public methods of ConcurrentHashMap is callable. You should limit the public methods.

Comment: Using `ConcurrentHashMap` seems reasonable, but subclassing it seems likely to be a terrible idea.  Delegate to it instead.

Comment: I didn't expect an answer that quickly! Thanks everyone! :D m-Power is a sort of managed Java EE environment that manages a SQL server (MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc.) along with JSP & Freemarker, also permitting custom code via Java classes, C/C++ classes, COBOL code, RPG/RPGLE code, & command language. Thankfully the environment gives full control to the external code whenever it runs.

Comment: As for subclassing, I figured it wasn't a good idea, since I just need a class that has most of the same functionality, albeit some minor changes, like having ConcurrentNavigableMap methods to be able to move between each record and also track position of the current record being modified.